# Docker linux Xdebug only works though remote_connect_back

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am working on setting up Docker + PhpStorm + Xdebug

If I enable `remote_connect_back`, PHP (Xdebug) is able to connect back to PhpStorm for visits through a web browsers.

However for executing scripts on the server, I'd like to be able to connect through the `remote_host` instead.

This is my xdebug.ini file:

```
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.idekey=testide
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_log_level=10
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=172.23.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=8000
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

From inside of the container I am able to see `172.23.0.1:8000`, however the path mappings doesn't work when using `remote_host`, only when using `remote_connect_back`.

Any tips or help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Check Xdebug log for the successful debug session and see what IP address is used there. Then specify it in the `remote_host`. P.S. If host OS is Windows or MacOS then you may use `remote_host=host.docker.internal` 2) That's assumes that both working and not working are the same "web page debug". If not working is a CLI script ... then you may need to specify the server name so that PhpStorm knows what "Server" entry to use (using `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` env variable)...

Comment: @LazyOne I am using both Windows and Linux. On windows, just providing the `host.docker.internal` as the `remote_host` works. However on linux this host doesn't seem to be defined well.

Comment: `host.docker.internal` is available for Mac/Windows but not Linux -- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264 . Try this possible workaround or similar to that: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-385698947

Comment: @LazyOne your links as well as the updates to xdebug on their page helped to resolve this in a meaningful way. (https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide)  Thank you!.